# Simple JavaScript events: alert using inline and traditional methods

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have been looking at the following code for a few minutes and the problem is escaping me. How can I make each of these events that produce alerts work?

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

[ <span id="trad_alert">traditional alert</span> ]

[ <span onclick="inlineAlert ();">inline alert</span> ]

<script type="txt/javascript">
document.getElementById("trad_alert").onclick = function () {
    alert ("traditional alert");
}

function inlineAlert () {
    alert ("inline alert");
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Searching Stack Overflow or the web produce numerous examples that appear identical to what I'm trying, but yet mine continues to fail.

Comment: It looked ok to me too so I pushed it to jsbin (http://jsbin.com/afajo5/edit) and it ran just fine. At least in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script type is wrong.

Either change it to `<script type="text/javascript">` or remove the `type` altogether.

Comment: Oh man thanks a lot! I was feeling seriously stumped before your post, although now I feel seriously stupid! :) It is times like this that I really miss compiler error messages.

Comment: @sosc: welcome to the wonderful world of scripting :) (and it's always nice to mark an answer as "accepted" if it fixes your problem :))

Comment: @jaaulde: It's my *blazingly* fast typing ;)

Comment: @Demian: Your reply was the first and was too fast to be identified by stackoverflow! There was a necessary grace period after posting before it could be accepted... the first one I saw displayed required three minutes.

Comment: @sosc: LOL - was unaware of that :)

Answer (score 4):

If I change the mime type on the script block to `text/javascript` (you have `txt`) it works fine for me in Fx4.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an e in `text/javascript`. It works with one:

http://jsfiddle.net/kFUMX/

Have a look at [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) for javascript debugging too.